# [MySQL Server] MySQL Workbench can't find my.cnf on (clean installation of) Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, mysql, macos

I have a clean installation of Snow Leopard on a MacBook and I want to get a MySQL Server running on it. I downloaded and installed the .dmg file provided by the homepage of MySQL and installed it. I did not yet try to start the server. I installed Workbench and configured it to localhost (standard settings). Now **Workbench keeps telling me, that it could not find the file `/etc/my.cnf`**. I was able to start the MySQL-Server from within Workbench, though. Now **Workbench wants to add a `/etc/my.cnf` file. Shall I proceed or is the file somewhere else already?

`locate my.cnf` tells me

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.13-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.13-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.13-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
```

Is it possible, that it is one of those? I don't want to mess the configuration up by creating a new `my.cnf` so I hope for an inspiration by some expert. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to copy one of the example files into the /etc directory or make your own. You won't have any problems until you ever want to have more than one version of mysql installed and running - then you can set up shell variables to keep things apart - but for the short run - one file in one place would be good. So let the Workbench make **`/etc/my.cnf`** and the other files will probably be ignored since Workbench looks to be telling you it looks only in `/etc`.

Comment: I assume by *example files* you mean, the files I listed above (after the `locate` command)? Another question: Do I understand it right, that the content of `/etc/conf` (assuming it exists) can be modifyed by Workbench?

Comment: Yes to _example files_ and Yes - I believe so. I don't have any of the files loaded on my mac to inspect - but as long as the user running the Workbench can create the file (or edit it once it's in place) Mac OS X won't prevent you from editing the file in /etc (which really is a link to /private/etc) As far as Mac - there is nothing special about MySql or the workbench so you might need to ask in the power users forum if no-one here has specific knowledge of that mysql tool.

Comment: I will ask in the power user forum for this explicit detail. And thanks for your answer(s) so far.